# read from a file that contains binary numbers disguised in random characters c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read from a file that contains binary numbers and change them to ints and store them in an array. The problem is when I try to look at the file the numbers are disguised as random nonsensical characters. Here is what the file looks like,

\æFQÆ3QËDO':^ÞC2-%<ýÁ-ã+)=ó> M­ù
¯M^££ÚUWæÑB5q'Ô¡r2ø7grh-6a¦4bï ¡!$imÁ|BW@0U³z½]Nµ)?J¢gÕ.W-jumÖ8/ s&²-§niJC~·Bº3¸Rãk+x&ãkÎp«éÌEÓ-Üy`ùo¬¦+®<%j`NN#L

I wrote a function to try and reading it but it is not working here is that function:

```
void readf2()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("f2");
    std::string line;
    int num;
    while(!inFile.eof()){
     std::getline(inFile,line);
     num = atoi(line.c_str());
     cout<<num;
     cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to properly read this file in. How should I go about it. is `atoi` incorrect or should I be trying something like `strtoi`? Thank all in advance.

Comment: Do you have any more information on the file? I'm guessing the file is filled with 32 or 64 bit numbers (taking up 4 or 8 bytes each). Binary files store information very compactly but you need to know how it is formatted to be able to read it. Looking at the raw information in character form won't help at all as it's not actually characters, it's just numbers. Did you make the file?

Comment: I did not make the file and the only information given is that the file "contains a set of binary numbers" that is it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary data are *not* characters. You can't read them as characters, and can't use string input (like `std::getline`) to read from the file.

To start with, you should open the file in *binary* mode:

```
std::ifstream inFile("f2", std::ios_base::binary);
```

Then read using unformated non-text functions, such as [`std::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read):

```
std::int32_t buffer[512];
while (inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), sizeof(buffer)) { ... }
```

If the read operation succeeds, you have an array of *up to* 512 32-bit integers (use [`std::istream::gcount`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) to find out how many *bytes* was read).

Also note the idiomatic way to read in a loop. When you do e.g. `while (!inFile.eof())` then you risk attempting to read once to many, as the EOF flag is not set until *after* a read operation fails.

---

If you do not know the format of the data in the file, it will be hard to say if the above reading is in any way correct. The data may be a structure containing a mix of 8 to 64 bit values, floating point values or even actual textual characters.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll be trying this now! I appreciate the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file as a binary file. You are opening it as a text file. Look here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Look at the ios::binary part.

Comment: In addition, you may want to mention other things he's doing such as calling `getline()` and `atoi()`.